# Send both parameters and Body data with JMeter HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

I need to send POST requests to an API server for which I need to send the following information:
Server:

- exampleapiserver.com

Methods:

- method1
- method2
- etc

Parameters:

- apikey: {apikey}
- env:{environment}

Headers:

- header1:{header1}
- header2:{header2}
- header3:{header3}

Body data:
{

- "bodydata1":{bodydata1}
- "bodydata2":{bodydata2}
- "bodydata3":{bodydata3}

}

The thing is that I can't send them both, both the parameters for the API server and the body data, and one with the other doesn't work.

As a workaround to make it happen, I used in my HTTP Request for the path the url with parameters, like this:

Server name or IP: exampleapiserver.com

Path: /method1?apikey=apiserverkey&env=test

and in the body data I've put the actual body data.

Can this be achieved in a different way, not to be forced to use the parameters in the URL so that I can send the body data too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you did it is ok.
As of jmeter 2.13 there is no other way to do it.